# Beginner - does the Quantity Theory of Money only apply to stablecoins if the coin has a secondary market?

Tags: quantity-theory-of-money

I have recently been reading up on how stablecoins are pegged to fiat currencies, and in doing so, have come across QTM as a means to justify their algorithm. Am I right to say, that this theory may* hold true if and only if the coin is traded on a secondary market?
I understand that the majority of stablecoin is used as a safety haven asset for the wider crypto market trading and thus can lead to price fluctuations depending on the broader macro environment, but if for example a coin was simply used as a means of exchange and no secondary market existed, would I be right to say that V = T and hence M = P?

Please keep in mind I am neither an expert in stablecoins or economics, just very curious...

Comment: "*Am I right to say, that this theory may hold true if and only if the coin is traded on a secondary market?*" Is the theory you are referring to here QTM? Because that exists quite independently of cryptocurrency, so it may hold true without any coin doing anything.

Comment: In the equations V = T and M = P the units of measurements do not match. In the equation MV=PT, the units of measurement are: a currency unit for M, 1/time unit for V, currency unit/unit of good/basket for P, unit of good/basket for T.

Comment: Taking these into consideration please clarify your exact question (if it was not answered by the comments).